# improve shell script awk & sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I want to monitor Disk IO of a server and want to set different threshold for

- the warning `if %busy above 60%` and
- error `if %busy above 80%`.

From sar output need to find error disk with more than 80% busy and on 2nd line need disk more than 60 but less than 80% busy if disk not crossing theresholds then it should print 'ok' for respective category

I've created a script which will do this, but is there a better way to run `sar` just one time and use the same output for error & warning threshold? My system is AIX 6.1.

```
sar -d 2 2 |sed -n '/Average/,$p'|
     sed -e 's/Average//g'|
     awk 'NR> 1 {
         if ($2 >80) {
             print $1, $2; f=1
         }  
     }
     END { if (!f) print "ok" }'

sar -d 2 2 |
    sed -n '/Average/,$p'|
    sed -e 's/Average//g'|
    awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >60 && $2 <81)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'
```

Pls find my updated script below

```
bash-3.00$ cat diskio.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`sar -d 2 2 |sed -n '/Average/,$ {s/Average//g;p;}'`
e=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >40)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
w=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 <40 && $2 >20)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
echo $e
echo $w

bash-3.00$ sh -v diskio.sh
#!/bin/bash
a=`sar -d 2 2 |sed -n '/Average/,$ {s/Average//g;p;}'`
e=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >40)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`
diskio.sh[3]: hdisk18:  not found.
w=`$a|awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 <40 && $2 >20)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
    END { if (!f) print "ok" }'`

diskio.sh[4]: hdisk18:  not found.
echo $e
ok
echo $w
ok
bash-3.00$ sar -d 2 2 |
    sed -n '/Average/,$ {s/Average//g;p;}'|
        awk 'NR> 1{ if ($2 >40)  { print $1, $2; f=1; }  }
        END { if (!f) print "ok" }'

hdisk79 135
hdisk101 85
bash-3.00$
```

Comment: It's sounds as if you need a *variable*.

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output if you'd like help writing a script to do something. Input to your script would apparently be the output of `sar -d 2 2`, whatever that looks like.

Answer (score 2):

This can be shorten some.

```
sar -d 2 2 | awk '/Average/ {t=1;next} t && NR>1 && $2>80 {print $1,$2;f=1} END { if (!f) print "ok" }'
```

---

This should do what you want

```
sar -d 2 2 | awk '/Average/ {t=1;next} t && NR>1 {if ($2>80) h=1;if ($2>60) l=1} END {if (h) {print "80+";exit};if (l) print "60+"}'
```

It will print `60+` if its above `60` and `80+` above `80`

---

Or store it to a variable

```
status=$(sar -d 2 2 | awk '/Average/ {t=1;next} t && NR>1 {if ($2>80) h=1;if ($2>60) l=1} END {if (h) {print "H";exit};if (l) print "L"}')
```

Here it set `status` to `L` for `60+` and `H` for `80+`

---

This should also print the status:

```
sar -d 2 2 | awk '/Average/ {t=1;next} t && NR>1 {if ($2>80) h=1;if ($2>60) {print $1,$2;l=1}} END {if (!l) print "ok"}'
```

Comment: thx jotne if you check my script it will publish hdisk(no) and % utilized value, i tried both of your scripts but i also need disk details and values if its below threshold it should just print 'ok'

Comment: How do you like to differentiate if its above 60% or above 80%, when you only like to print the disks above limit and print ok?  This will be the same as print all above 60% or OK if not.

Comment: thx again jotne seems getting near solution, but how do i differentiate error & warning  because i'll use this script for alerts and need to have relevant alerts (with details) based on thresholds

Comment: ok to make clear my requirement further output should be something like this errors will be shown on 1st line by using pipe tr "\\n" "," and warnings will be shown with values on 2nd line....

Comment: You can save warning and error to different files, is that OK?  So 60% + to one file and 80%+ to another file?  And both file "ok" if no 60% or below.  All depends on what you like to do with the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41000/discussion-between-tnt5273-and-jotne)

Comment: from sar output need to find error disk with more than 80% busy and on 2nd line need disk more than 60 but less than 80% busy if disk not crossing thresholds then it should print 'ok' for respective category

Comment: Please provide with sample output, still not understand who you like it.  Output to file?  More than one file? Output to variable? OK to both file/variable if ok?

Comment: hi jotne I've added script with output to my question hope it helps you with my requirement

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/Average/,$p'|sed -e 's/Average//g'
```

could be replaced by

```
sed -n '/Average/,$ {s/Average//g;p;}'
```

but sed does not make any evaluation of value (compare) easily so the awk for all is a better solution